# pygetwindow getWindowsWithTitle problems on macos

Tags: macos, process, window

I've been trying to use pygetwindow and everything works perfectly fine. But I can't find the function getWindowsWithTitle. This is my code rn:

```
import pygetwindow as gw

window = gw.getWindowsWithTitle("Google Chrome")
```

and it just does not find the command:

```
AttributeError: module 'pygetwindow' has no attribute 'getWindowsWithTitle'
```

Is this function not avaliable on mac? I'm trying to find and minimize a specific app. Are there any other ways of achiving so? I noticed that there is a `getWindowsAt` function. Would that do the job?